# Line by line modifications in Unix

Tags: find, text

I am looking for a way to do the following with a pipe delimited file in UNIX, for EACH LINE and am not sure where to start:

1. Look for a character in a line of text (assume using GREP?)
2. If found then add some text at the end of that line (using SED?)
3. If not found then look for another character in the same line
4. If found add text at end of the line else do nothing
5. LOOP FOR ALL LINES IN THE FILE

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

This is all `sed` work, you don't need extra tools:

Say you want to add `foo` at the end of line containing an `f` and `bar` at the end of lines without `f`, but with a `b`

```
sed '/f/{
  s/$/foo/
  b
  }
/b/s/$/bar/'
```

You can "address" lines with `/pattern/`, so the following commands are only executed if they contain the pattern. So in the example, only lines that contain an `f` trigger the execution of the `s` replacement and the `b` (the `{}` group the commands, so everything inside is only applied if the address matched. The `b` branches to the end of the script to avoid appending another string for a matching `b`.

Different approach without branch:

```
sed '/f/s/$/foo/;s/^[^f]*b[^f]*$/&bar/'
```

As an exercise, you can figure this out yourself with some `sed` knowledge, using `man sed` if neccessary.

Comment: or `/f/s/$/foo/;/f/!{/b/s/$/bar/}` or even `/f/s/$/foo/;t;/b/s/$/bar/;:`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add the same text string at the end of line for both the 
scenarios(chars to look for: 'X' 'Y') then you can do it as follows:

```
sed -e 's/[XY].*/&__ADDEDTEXT__/' yourfile
```

On the other hand, if you wanted separate texts placed at the end of lines depending on the char, then you may do:

```
sed -e '
   /X/s/$/__TEXT1__/; t
   /Y/s/$/__TEXT2__/
' yourfile
```

Where we make use of the `t` (read as test) command to detect whether the prevous `s///` command was successful and jump to the end of sed code on the present line. Also, note the syntax: /regex/s/// => if a line comprises the regex then perform the substitution on the line.

Answer (score 0):

Perl is also a useful tool that can easily do everything in one go.

So with @Philippos example, a perl program would look like this (some of the syntax is optional and was added for clarification):

```
perl -pe '(m/f/&&s/$/foo/)||(m/b/&&s/$/bar/)' file
```

This reads `file` and outputs the result. You can also "edit" the file in place by using `-pi -e` instead of `-pe` ( `-i` means "in place"), so:

```
perl -pi -e '(m/f/&&s/$/foo/)||(m/b/&&s/$/bar/)' file
```

There's probably also a way to do this with `awk` though initial testing failed me (I'm not that proficient in AWK), with Ruby (which looks almost the same, ping me if you want examples) and it can be fun in pure Bash.